# How to add minimum coverage rules for multi module project as a cumulative number

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

Given a multi module project built using **Gradle 5.0**, I want to enforce over all code coverage using jacoco.
I am able to set the coverage enforcement at a module level. But due to the nature of the dependencies, many tests are written in an integration module which cover most of the code. So I want to fail the build ***only if*** overall code coverage fails below certain threshold.
Below is my build.gradle and build does not fail no matter what value I set for cumulative coverage.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    tasks.withType(JacocoReport).all {
        reports {
            html.enabled true
        }
        check.dependsOn it
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        executionData = fileTree("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
        subprojects.each {
            sourceSets it.sourceSets.main
            dependsOn it.test
        }
    }

    jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        executionData fileTree("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")

        violationRules {
            rule {
                limit {
                    counter = 'LINE'
                    minimum = 0.5 //individual module coverage level
                }
                failOnViolation true
            }
        }
    }
    tasks.build.dependsOn(jacocoTestReport)
    tasks.build.dependsOn(jacocoTestCoverageVerification)
    jacocoTestReport.mustRunAfter jacocoTestCoverageVerification
    check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification  
}

//overall cumulative coverage report
task jacocoMergeTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include('*/build/jacoco/*.exec')
    subprojects.each {
        sourceSets it.sourceSets.main
        dependsOn it.test
    }
    reports {
        html {
            enabled true
            destination rootProject.file("$rootProject.buildDir/reports/jacoco/html")
        }
    }
}
//overall cumulative coverage tasks
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    def execFilesToInclude = subprojects.collect {
        it.name+"build/jacoco/*.exec"
    }
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include(execFilesToInclude)

    violationRules {
        rule {
            element = 'CLASS'
            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                minimum = 0.8 //no matter which value I set, build does not fail
            }
            failOnViolation true
        }
    }
}
tasks.build.dependsOn jacocoMergeTestReport
tasks.build.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```